# TextView. Fade out text at the top while going off screen kind of like in Star Wars

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, fade

I am trying to fade out the top of my textview as the text goes off screen. I want it to look kind of like the Star Wars credits but keep its width. I have been working with this code but it just turns my screen black.

```
 if let containerView = textView.superview {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer(layer: containerView.layer)
        gradient.frame = containerView.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.85)
        containerView.layer.mask = gradient
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the force?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the same with one third party library.

Please try this one. : https://github.com/somtd/SWScrollView

It is transforming the textView inside the scrollview and here is the code for the same:

```
- (void)setupScrollPerspective
{
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    //z distance
    float distance = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    float ratio    = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    transform.m34 = - ratio / distance;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 60.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    self.layer.transform = transform;
    self.layer.zPosition = distance * ratio;
    self.layer.position = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2,
                                      [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/3);
}
```

[image]

I hope you want the similar thing.....

Comment: I just want the top to fade out.